# Meta tags doesn't work with Vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm using Vue webpack template: `vue init webpack router-app`

Setting meta titles in "router-app/src/router/index.js":

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '*',
      component: NotFoundComponent
    },
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'LoginPage',
      meta: { title: 'Home', bodyClass: 'dashboard' },
      component: LoginPage
    }
  ]
})
```

LoginPage.vue:

```
<template>
  <form>
  ...
  </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'LoginPage',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Login Page'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

But it doesn't affect my meta title at all. In a vue dev-tools (Chrome) i can see that `$route` has my meta tags.

Comment: Did you include a navigation guard?

Comment: What does your template look like? I'm pretty sure `title` isn't set automatically

Comment: @Phil added my template file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you didn't include navigation guard, here is a function from a great article [here](https://alligator.io/vuejs/vue-router-modify-head/). And its working fine.

If you only need to change the title you can do it like this

```
meta: {
  title: 'About Page - Example App'
}
```

Insert this in your `route.js` or (if not `app.js`)

```
 router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

    const nearestWithTitle = to.matched.slice().reverse().find(r => r.meta && r.meta.title);

    if (nearestWithTitle) document.title = nearestWithTitle.meta.title;

    next();
});
```

If you need to change the meta tags' name and others as well then you need to whole function for flexibility

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

    const nearestWithTitle = to.matched.slice().reverse().find(r => r.meta && r.meta.title);

    const nearestWithMeta = to.matched.slice().reverse().find(r => r.meta && r.meta.metaTags);
    const previousNearestWithMeta = from.matched.slice().reverse().find(r => r.meta && r.meta.metaTags);

    if (nearestWithTitle) document.title = nearestWithTitle.meta.title;

    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-vue-router-controlled]')).map(el => el.parentNode.removeChild(el));

    if (!nearestWithMeta) return next();

    nearestWithMeta.meta.metaTags.map(tagDef => {
            const tag = document.createElement('meta');

            Object.keys(tagDef).forEach(key => {
                tag.setAttribute(key, tagDef[key]);
            });

            tag.setAttribute('data-vue-router-controlled', '');

            return tag;
        })
        .forEach(tag => document.head.appendChild(tag));

    next();
});
```

Comment: How to adopt it to my code - i'm using `export default new Router({})` so i can't call it `router.beforeEach`

Comment: you can put it in app.js before the `new Vue(`... line or create another file for flexibility say `metaguard.js`...

Comment: Sorry, but i'm noob yet with Vuejs, if i place your code `router.beforeEach` before `export default new Router` then i'll get an error about `router` is not defined.

Comment: It's okay bro. No not in your `router/index.js` but `app.js` where you import your routes, because it checks the routes before redirecting.

Comment: Ok, it works, could you explain, please, why it has to be above `new Vue` in main.js?

Comment: It must be before new Vue because your router must be initialize first before mounting your app just like declaring a variable first before calling it.